# rake aborted! Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$c_blue"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, spree

I am building a spree store and everything works in development but when i try to push to production with git push heroku master I am getting the following error:

```
       rake aborted!
       Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$c_blue".
       (in /tmp/build_1a624a4f-adf9-4627-a2ce-22692ef03d87/app/assets/stylesheets/spree/fancy/shared
/_layout.scss:2)
```

I am using a custom theme called spree_fancy: https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy

This is my variable.css.scss file:

```
/*--------------------------------------*/
/* Colors
/*--------------------------------------*/
$c_green:       #8dba53 !default;  /* Spree green    */
$c_red:         #e45353 !default;  /* Error red      */
$c_blue:        #50A2F3 !default;
$c_orange:      #ff9600 !default;

$layout_background_color:   #FFFFFF !default;
$title_text_color:          #404042 !default;
$body_text_color:           #919191 !default;
$link_text_color:           #61a1f0 !default;

$product_background_color:  #FFFFFF !default;
$product_title_text_color:  #404042 !default;
$product_body_text_color:   #404042 !default;
$product_link_text_color:   #BBBBBB !default;

/* -------------------------------------------- */
/* Load "Open Sans" font from Google Fonts
/* -------------------------------------------- */
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,300,400,600);

/*--------------------------------------*/
/* Font families
/*--------------------------------------*/
$ff_base:       'Open Sans', sans-serif !default;

/*--------------------------------------
  | Font sizes
  |--------------------------------------
  |- Navigation                         
  |                                    */
      $header_navigation_font_size:           16px !default;
      $horizontal_navigation_font_size:       16px !default;
      $main_navigation_header_font_size:      16px !default;
      $main_navigation_font_size:             14px !default;
/*|------------------------------------
  |- Product Listing                         
  |                                  */
      $product_list_name_font_size:           14px !default;
      $product_list_price_font_size:          16px !default;
      $product_list_header_font_size:         20px !default;
      $product_list_search_font_size:         16px !default;
/*|------------------------------------
  |- Product Details
  |                                  */
      $product_detail_name_font_size:         24px !default;
      $product_detail_description_font_size:  16px !default;
      $product_detail_price_font_size:        20px !default;
      $product_detail_title_font_size:        16px !default;
/*|------------------------------------
  |- Basic
  |                                  */
      $heading_font_size:                     24px !default;
      $sub_heading_font_size:                 16px !default;
      $button_font_size:                      12px !default;
      $input_box_font_size:                   13px !default;
      $base_font_size:                        16px !default;
      $border_color:                          lighten($body_text_color, 30) !default;
      $default_border:                        1px solid $border_color !default;
      $button_border_color:                   rgba(0, 138, 189, .75) !default;
      $table_head_color:                      lighten($body_text_color, 60) !default;
```

This is my _layout.scss file

```
body {
  border-top: 5px solid $c_blue;
  padding-top: 10px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.page-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  @include transition-duration(0.2s);
}

.hidden { display: none }

#logo {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#welcome-message {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;

  h1 {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: $body_text_color;

    a {
      color: $c_orange;

      &:hover {
        color: $c_green !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

#latest-products {
  h3 { color: $c_orange }
  hr { border-bottom-color: lighten($c_orange, 40) }

  .product-image a { border-color: lighten($c_orange, 40) }
  .product-name { color: $c_orange !important; }

  .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active,
  .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover {
    background-color: $c_orange !important;
  }
}

#featured-products {
  h3 { color: $c_blue }
  hr { border-bottom-color: lighten($c_blue, 30) }

  .product-image a { border-color: lighten($c_blue, 30) }

  .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a.active,
  .bx-pager.bx-default-pager a:hover {
    background-color: $c_blue !important;
  }
}

#latest-products, #featured-products {
  margin: 40px 0 ;
  text-align: center;

  .bx-wrapper {
    margin-top: 40px;

    .bx-controls {
      bottom: inherit;
      top: -35px;
    }
  }

  h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  hr {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -15px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
  }

  ul {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }

  .product-image {
    a {
      @include border-radius(165px);
      border-width: 2px;
      width: 160px;
      height: 160px;
    }

    img {
      @include border-radius(45px);
    }
  }
}

#sidebar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

ul#products {
  max-width: 600px;
}

ul#products li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  a.info {
    height: inherit;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: $c_green;
  }

  .price {
    font-size: 24px;
  }

  .product-image {
    border: none;
    min-height: 155px;
    padding: 0;

    a {
      border-color: lighten($c_blue, 30);
      border-width: 2px;
      padding: 30px 22px 30px 20px;
      float: none;

      img {
        @include border-radius(0);
      }
    }
  }
}

#wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
}


#sidebar_products_search {
  .filter-title {
    color: $c_blue;
    border-color: lighten($c_blue, 30);
  }

  .filter_choices {
    font-size: 14px;
    list-style: none;
  }
}


.taxons-list {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

footer#footer {
  @include single-box-shadow(darken($c_blue, 10), 0, 0, 15px, 0, true);
  // background: image-url("spree/fancy/footer-bg.png") repeat center;
  background-color: lighten($c_blue, 5);
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-top: 5px solid lighten($c_blue, 30);
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;

  &, a, h5 {
    color: white;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: lighten($c_green, 30) !important;
  }

  h5 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  p {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: none;

    li {

    }
  }
}
```

This is my fancy.scss file:

```
/*
 = require jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom
 = require jquery.bxslider
 = require icons
 = require icons-codes
*/

@import 'compass';

@import 'compass/css3';

@import 'spree/fancy/variables';
@import 'spree/fancy/variables_override';

@import 'spree/fancy/shared/typography';
@import 'spree/fancy/shared/forms';
@import 'spree/fancy/shared/layout';
@import 'spree/fancy/shared/tables';

@import 'spree/fancy/components/slider';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/product_item';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/search';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/cart';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/breadcrumbs';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/variants';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/messages';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/navigation';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pagination';


@import 'spree/fancy/sections/checkout';
@import 'spree/fancy/sections/cart';
@import 'spree/fancy/sections/user';
@import 'spree/fancy/sections/contact_us';

@import 'spree/fancy/shared/media';

/*----- These are the static pages below --------*/

@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/about';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/contact';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/distribution';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/faq';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/manufacturers';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/pickup';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/returns';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/services';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/shipping';
@import 'spree/fancy/components/pages/suppliers';
```

Something weird that I noticed is that on my fancy.scss file the line that says @import 'compass/css3'; looks a bit different than the rest in that file. The 3 in css3 is purple in color while all the rest of the code in that file is white. Might that import not be working for some reason?

Any other ideas of what is going on?

This is my Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/spree/spree_fancy.git
  revision: bdeaeb9ced29a4e3204d8bc9988b57808b5a71d8
  branch: 2-2-stable
  specs:
    spree_fancy (1.3.0)
      compass-rails
      deface (~> 1.0.0rc3)
      jquery-ui-rails
      spree_core (~> 2.2)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git
  revision: 81a0fbb2db15efbbb50d0d139bbc41aee7fa58a1
  branch: 2-2-stable
  specs:
    spree_auth_devise (2.2.0)
      cancan (~> 1.6.10)
      devise (~> 3.2.3)
      devise-encryptable (= 0.1.2)
      json
      multi_json
      spree_core (~> 2.2.0)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
  revision: ea9dd046848523c79845abbd5462f5e13941276e
  branch: 2-2-stable
  specs:
    spree_gateway (2.2.1)
      spree_core (~> 2.2.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.5)
      actionpack (= 4.0.5)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    active_utils (2.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      i18n
    activemerchant (1.42.9)
      active_utils (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14, < 5.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2, < 4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
      json (~> 1.7)
      money (< 7.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
    activemodel (4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.5)
      activemodel (= 4.0.5)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.5)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    acts_as_list (0.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    arel (4.0.2)
    awesome_nested_set (3.0.0.rc.5)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    aws-sdk (1.27.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
      uuidtools (~> 2.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.7-x86-mingw32)
    builder (3.1.4)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    canonical-rails (0.0.7)
      rails (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    chunky_png (1.3.1)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    colorize (0.7.3)
    compass (0.12.6)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.2.19)
    compass-rails (1.1.7)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
      sprockets (<= 2.11.0)
    deface (1.0.0)
      colorize (>= 0.5.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    devise (3.2.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-encryptable (0.1.2)
      devise (>= 2.1.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.0)
    ffaker (1.24.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.1.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    friendly_id (5.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    highline (1.6.21)
    hike (1.2.3)
    httparty (0.13.1)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jbuilder (1.5.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (4.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.15.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.0)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    monetize (0.3.0)
      money (~> 6.1.0.beta1)
    money (6.1.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6.4)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    nokogiri (1.6.2.1-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (3.4.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.0)
      mime-types
    paranoia (2.0.2)
      activerecord (~> 4.0)
    pg (0.15.1-x86-mingw32)
    polyamorous (0.6.4)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rabl (0.9.3)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.5)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.5)
      actionpack (= 4.0.5)
      activerecord (= 4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.5)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.2)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.5)
      actionpack (= 4.0.5)
      activesupport (= 4.0.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    ransack (1.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      polyamorous (~> 0.6.0)
    rdoc (4.1.1)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      rdoc (~> 4.0, < 5.0)
    select2-rails (3.4.9)
      sass-rails
      thor (~> 0.14)
    spree (2.2.2)
      spree_api (= 2.2.2)
      spree_backend (= 2.2.2)
      spree_cmd (= 2.2.2)
      spree_core (= 2.2.2)
      spree_frontend (= 2.2.2)
      spree_sample (= 2.2.2)
    spree_api (2.2.2)
      rabl (= 0.9.3)
      spree_core (= 2.2.2)
      versioncake (~> 1.2.0)
    spree_backend (2.2.2)
      jquery-rails (~> 3.1.0)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 4.1.0)
      select2-rails (~> 3.4.7)
      spree_api (= 2.2.2)
      spree_core (= 2.2.2)
    spree_cmd (2.2.2)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    spree_core (2.2.2)
      activemerchant (~> 1.42.3)
      acts_as_list (= 0.3.0)
      awesome_nested_set (~> 3.0.0.rc.3)
      aws-sdk (= 1.27.0)
      cancan (~> 1.6.10)
      deface (~> 1.0.0)
      ffaker (~> 1.16)
      font-awesome-rails (~> 4.0)
      friendly_id (= 5.0.3)
      highline (~> 1.6.18)
      httparty (~> 0.11)
      json (~> 1.7)
      kaminari (~> 0.15.0)
      monetize
      paperclip (~> 3.4.1)
      paranoia (~> 2.0)
      rails (~> 4.0.5)
      ransack (~> 1.1.0)
      state_machine (= 1.2.0)
      stringex (~> 1.5.1)
      truncate_html (= 0.9.2)
    spree_frontend (2.2.2)
      canonical-rails (~> 0.0.4)
      jquery-rails (~> 3.1.0)
      spree_api (= 2.2.2)
      spree_core (= 2.2.2)
      stringex (~> 1.5.1)
    spree_sample (2.2.2)
      spree_core (= 2.2.2)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9-x86-mingw32)
    state_machine (1.2.0)
    stringex (1.5.1)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    truncate_html (0.9.2)
    turbolinks (2.2.2)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.39)
    uglifier (2.5.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    uuidtools (2.1.4)
    versioncake (1.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      railties (>= 3.2)
      tzinfo
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.0.5)
  rails_12factor
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.2)
  sdoc
  spree (= 2.2.2)
  spree_auth_devise!
  spree_fancy!
  spree_gateway!
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'spree', '2.2.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
gem 'spree_fancy', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_fancy.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'
```

Comment: Have you precompiled production assets before pushing? `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I get the same error by running that command :/

Comment: I do not see the file import `variable.css.scss`? (I’m not familiar with RoR) _Edit: I see that `$c_blue` is declared in spree therefore it is another problem._
Note : type `@import 'compass'; @import 'compass/css3';` is redundant because `@import 'compass';` already import the `compass/css3` module.

Comment: Can you please post your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: @gmacdougall I've updated my questions with the Gemfile.lock and Gemfile know what is going on? I found this issue int he documentation I am going through but nothing is working it seems: https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/issues/41

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to 2-1-stable?

Comment: Nope, I will try that if no one can solve this.

Comment: Try importing variable.css.scss into fancy.scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured that out.
The problem is in your application.css file. There is an example app link from spree-fancy project issue:

https://github.com/vike27/surplusmerchant2/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Look at `*= require_tree .` directive. That tolds the Sass gem to require all subdirectories recursively. And it starts NOT from fancy.css file but from nested subdirectories. So it fails on the first file that uses any variable because no variables loaded yet!

Just replace `*= require_tree .` with `*= require ./spree/fancy` and that's all.